# bash:python3.3 no such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash

I recently installed a /usr/local copy of python3.3.2 and when convinced it was solid, re-installed under /usr and removed the /usr/local version.  When I run the executable as /usr/bin/python3.3, everything is fine but when I run it as 'python3.3' I get the message:

```
> python3.3
bash: /usr/local/bin/python3.3: No such file or directory
```

'which' finds /usr/bin/python3.3.  I did a 'set -u' and 'set echo' trying to figure out what is going on without success.  How is bash getting in here?

Thank you.
Steve S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your executable file is still remembered by the shell as if it's done with hash:

```
hash: hash [-lr] [-p pathname] [-dt] [name ...]
    Remember or display program locations.

    Determine and remember the full pathname of each command NAME.  If
    no arguments are given, information about remembered commands is displayed.

      -r                forget all remembered locations
```

Running `hash -r` without needing to restart your shell would fix that.

Update: Actually the shell also remembers it not just by running through hash. Perhaps when you try to execute it or do things like `type -P prog`, the shell would remember it already. This is the error I had on my test and I didn't run `w`:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/w: No such file or directory
```

And `hash -r` fixed it.

Comment: Ah -- thank you very much.  That fixed it.  I tried 'rehash' from my old sun/unix/c-shell days and that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `bash` is caching the previous location of `python3.3` somewhere. Try closing your shell and logging in once again - that should wipe the cache and allow `bash` to pick up the proper location of `python3.3`.